# best method to use GoogleApiClient in Android

Tags: android, google-api

i'm tryin to figure out what is the best method to build GoogleApiClient in my App, in many tutorial on the internet show that i have to build the GoogleApiClient in Activity. But what if i need to use the GoogleApiClient in many classes including Fragments And Services. Is it possible to build the GoogleApiClient inside Application Class, so i can call it in another class without to build it again ?